# Decrypting an unknown file

Tags: file, encryption

I'm wondering whether it is possible to decrypt or code an editing software for a completely unknown file extension without actually knowing anything about the file except the unreadable text that's inside of it? If it is possible, where would I start off to find out how the file works and how it's structured?

Thank you.

Comment: If the file is *encrypted* then forget it. Otherwise, get a good hex editor, and start learning how different data types are encoded in binary format and what looks like in hex.  After awhile, you will start recognizing patterns, like integers, length-prefixed arrays, strings, etc.

Comment: There are various ways to (sometimes) determine what type of file it is (if it is indeed a standard type).  For example, a ZIP file always begins with the characters "PK".  But if the file is encrypted (with any decent encryption scheme) then there's no way to read it without the key.  (For examining files on Windows, "HDD Hex Editor Neo" is a good, free, "hex editor".)